# Excel - Find All Cells Containing Value and Change Background Color

Tags: macos, excel, function, search, background-color

How do I find all cells containing a text value such as merchant_id and change the background color of those cells to a specific color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro will use the current selected range and check each cell for `merchant_id`.  Then mark it maroon if true.  To pick a particular color, the best way is to record a macro and see what values it creates.  Take those numbers and replace the contents of the `With` block

```
Sub MarkCellsInSelection()
    For Each c In Selection
        If c.Value = "merchant_id" Then

            With c.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```